# Find the quadratic AND the cubic polynomial interpolating this data set?

Tags: interpolation, numerical-methods, numerical

I can't make heads or tails of how to do this question; I thought there was only one interpolating polynomial for a set of data points. Here is the data set:

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUOMq.png)

[0,0], [10,102.6903], [20,105.4529], [30,81.21744], [40,55.6016], [50,35.6859]

We are asked to first find the quadratic interpolating polynomial and then to find the cubic interpolating polynomial. This confuses me, as I thought that there should be only one interpolating polynomial of degree less than the number of points?

Could somebody help to explain how I would go about getting these two requested polynomials? Also, a follow on question: would the quadratic or the cubic be expected to give a better idea of the MAXIMUM concentration?

Thanks a lot!

**NOTE:** I've covered using Vandermonde Systems (simple linear solving), Lagrangian Basis and Divided-Difference Tables to interpolate points.

Comment: If you have a data set of n (x,y)-values, your interpolating polynom will be of degree n-1. This iss why your approaches (Vandermonde Systems,, Lagrangian Basis and Divided-Difference) won't solve your problem. They will give a polynomial of degree 5. You want to approximate your data.  As already said least square method would be a choice.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic interpolating polynomial requires exactly 3 points, and a cubic interpolating polynomial requires exactly 4 points. Clearly, more than that is given to you. So you have two ways of tackling this problem:

1. Choose 3 and 4 points for quadratic and cubic interpolation respectively, in the neighborhood of the possible maxima.
2. Use a least square approximation of the quadratic and cubic interpolating function using all the given points.

The maximum concentration is the maxima of the interpolating function obtained.

Note: The stackoverflow forum is mostly for programming related questions. Try posting such questions in the [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) forum to get better answers.